# How to watch variables in the developer console

Tags: apex, visualforce, developer-console

I'm having problems watching a variable in the developer console.

I have a function and I'd like to see what is going into it and what is being returned from it.

It's contingent upon some parameters

How can I achieve this using the web-based IDE?

Comment: You can add checkpoints by opening class in developer console or add system.debug() lines in your code.

Comment: where can I view the system.debug() lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the example class that I created in my Developer org:

```
public class SomeClass{
    public void someMethod(){
        Integer i =0;
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR,'i value is '+i);
    }
}
```

And I am invoking the method in the above class by using the below code in anonymous window:

```
SomeClass obj = new SomeClass();
obj.someMethod();
```

And here is what I see in the debug logs:

[image]

Comment: how would that work with an extension class?

Comment: if it is an extension class for Visualforce, While keeping developer console open, simulate your action on VF page and the logs will be recorded in the developer console.

Comment: and it's possible to pass a URL parameter to a developer console visualforce page?

Comment: If you meant how to debug the url parameters passed to VF page then you should add something like this in your controller or extension class `System.debug(ApexPages.currentPage.getParameters()); ` and then open the VF page by passing the url parameters and you should see the url parameters in the debug log.